# Create a Cloud Foundry Service from a hosted Cloud Foundry application

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I have a Cloud Foundry application hosted using Swisscom. One of the features I require from the application is that the user can set up a Cloud Foundry Service - Specifically the Swisscom Secrets-Store service. However, this is turning out to be a bit of a challenge.

Firstly, I used the [cloudfoundry-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudfoundry-cli) NPM module to create the service from my application much like the example provided:

```
const cf = require('cloudfoundry-cli')
cf.provisionService({
  name: 'mongoNo1',
  type: 'compose-for-mongodb',
  plan: 'Standard'
}, function(err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  console.log('Service provisioned')
})
```

This worked fine when I was running my application locally because obviously I have the CF CLI installed on my computer. However, when I pushed the application to Swisscom and tried to create the service nothing happened as the CF CLI isn't installed on the application.

I have also checked out [cf-nodejs-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cf-nodejs-client) which is suggested if you don't want to install the CF CLI by allowing you to pass your Cloud Foundry login details and API endpoint. However, I've checked the docs and it seems this NPM module doesn't allow you to create services. The [documents](https://prosociallearneu.github.io/cf-nodejs-client/docs/v0.12.0/Services.html) show you can either getService, getServicePlans, getServices, or remove - No option to create.

Worst case scenario I thought I could SSH into the running application and install the CF CLI, but for that you need root access which is not possible.

My question is - Is it possible to install the CF CLI on the application when it is being pushed? Perhaps a buildpack which can install the CF CLI when the application is being pushed? I have checked the list of community buildpacks and this doesn't seem to exist and I wouldn't know where to start creating one. Otherwise, does anyone know how to create Cloud Foundry services from a Node application without the need of the CF CLI.

Comment: You could use the API directly instead of relying on the CLI.

Comment: @lafunamor - Forgive me but I have no experience using CURL and APIs so I'm not really understanding the CF API. I took the example here https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/9.2.0/service_instances/creating_a_service_instance.html and changed the end point and space_guid but nothing seems to be happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to install the CF CLI on the application when it is being pushed?

One option would be to simply bundle the cf cli with your application. It's a static binary, so it's pretty easy to bundle with your app. The following should work.

1. Download the cf cli for Linux from [here](https://packages.cloudfoundry.org/stable?release=linux64-binary&source=github) & unzip it.
2. Put this into a folder that's under your application root. For example: `mkdir bin/` then move your binary from step #1 to the `bin/` folder.
3. Add a `.profile` file to the root of your application. In that file, put `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`, which will put the `bin/` directory from step #2 on the PATH (change `bin` to whatever you named that folder).

Now `cf push` your app. This will include the binary. When it starts up, the `.profile` script will execute and put the path to your `cf` binary on the PATH. Thus you can run `cf ...` commands in your container.

Hope that helps!